# Create DataGridTemplateColumn with Image and Text WPF

Tags: wpf, image, text, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am using this code to create a column that shows image and text, but only the text is appearing, what am I doing wrong?

DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                col1.Header = "MyHeader";

```
            FrameworkElementFactory factoryStackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel));
            factoryStackPanel.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);

            FrameworkElementFactory factoryTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock));
            Binding bindTextBlock = new Binding("[" + i + "]");
            factoryTextBlock.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty, bindTextBlock);
            factoryTextBlock.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
            factoryTextBlock.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

            FrameworkElementFactory factoryImage = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Image));
            Binding bindImage = new Binding("http://www.pgn.co.id/images/modules/logo_pgn.png");
            factoryImage.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, bindImage);

            factoryStackPanel.AppendChild(factoryImage);
            factoryStackPanel.AppendChild(factoryTextBlock);

            DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = factoryStackPanel };

            col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

            gridViewItens.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to do this stuff in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ed Plunkett said, it's much more clean to do it in XAML. Assuming that your `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of some items, and you item class has properties like `MyText` and `MyImage`, you could do something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Item">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridTemplateColumn uses a data template, which works in the same way as the data-template
features you explored with list controls earlier. The only difference in the DataGridTemplateColumn is that
it allows you to define two templates: one for data display (the CellTemplate) and one for data editing (the CellEditingTemplate), which you’ll consider shortly. Here’s an example that uses the template data column
to place a thumbnail image of each product in the grid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Image Stretch="None" Source=
"{Binding Path=ProductImagePath, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}">
</Image>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```